# Is there any way one could say "Hardcore Gamer"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, modern-life

I know it’s a bit silly since I don’t think there was a concept of a gamer back then but just curious if it’s possible to make something close to that phrase?

Comment: "Back then"?? [Lingua latina vivit!](https://youtu.be/xj-zCfVC2Zg?t=3)

Comment: sorry, I mean when the latin language was at its peak. Not sure when that was but I’m assuming the Roman Empire era.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd say ***lusor studiosissimus***.

The word *lusor* means "player" in general, from *ludere*, and I don't think we should expect a closer hit for "gamer".

The adjective *studiosus* comes from *studium* and is more about eagerness and devotion than studying despite looking like many familiar words in modern languages.
I emphasized it further with the superlative.

To me the English implies video games while the Latin doesn't.
It refers to playing any games, so video games are certainly included.
If you want to specify the type of games involved, you need to supply details.
But in most use cases you shouldn't explain yourself too much at the expense of conciseness if major misinterpretation is unlikely.

Comment: Thank you. And yeah, I guess it falls in with video games more than anything. Do you think with better context it would make sense with `lusor studiosissimus` referring to video game player?

Comment: @JohhanSantana I added a sentence to clarify. It makes perfect sense to use the phrase for video games. It's broader than the English phrase but certainly includes video games.

Comment: There seems to be a neo-Latin word, _Videolusis_ for video games, though I can't find an originating source outside of its usage on some internet forums. Maybe that could be used to construct a more specific phrase?

Comment: @Adam You can always replace my *lusor* with *videolusor*, but it depends on context whether it will be necessary. My translation has the same denotation but a different connotation than the English when it comes to including specific game types, so no translation will be perfect. I'm not sure I buy *lusis*, but I'd be happy to see an answer elaborating on that or other options.

Comment: Perhaps we could coin a new word, _videolusor_; one who plays video games?

Comment: I'm not sure that would be a good idea. I'm reminded of A. W. Potts in "Hints Towards Latin Prose Composition" that advocates quite strongly against composite words in Latin for the most part. Looking around I managed to find the passage in question: (continuing)

Comment: "Lucretius endeavoured to enrich the vocabulary available for the high purposes of poetry by coining compound words such as *aedituentes*, *frugiferentes*, *navigerus*, *primigenus*, *silvifragus*, *suavidicus*, *tripectorus*, but neither his authority nor their sonorous dignity sufficed to recommend to his successors formations unsuited to the genius of the Latin tongue.", p. 13. (Continuing)

Comment: I think this advises at least caution that using compound words should be avoided for proper Latinitas. Maybe an adjective would be better suited for clarity? Maybe *lusor electronicorum studiosissimus*. A "devout player of electronic [games]"

Comment: @VictorBC I wouldn't use anything with *video-* in Latin unless I had the urgent need to be very specific and avoid the slightest misinterpretation. Usually just "gamer" will do, just like in English. Indeed, the best style to specify the matter in Latin would be to use an adjective. My first reaction would be *lusor computatralis*, which works at least if it's about computer games rather than console games. And that brings me to my recurring point: The best translation of a given phrase depends on context, not just the original phrase.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Very well said, I agree with you entirely. When I was an English teacher, whenever someone asked me what was the translation of X word in English, I invariably asked "What's the context?" because very frequently if I simply gave an answer, my students managed to find an application for it that made absolutely no sense in English but did make sense in Portuguese lol